# Convert varchar 12h a.m. p.m. to 24h time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, time, varchar

How can i convert a string from a 12hr format to time in SQL?

```
CONVERT( TIME(0), '12:00:00 a.m.' )
```

Comment: There's no special way to do this, just use string parsing and math to change it the way you want.   Did you try something and get an error?   Are you trying to change the varchar data type to a `time` datatype, or just change the format of the string, but keep it a string?

Comment: Is the format consistent across all your data or could it vary?

Comment: Your problem is that you are using `a.m.`. `am` without the dots would work

Comment: Yes and i founded there where spaces also between a. and m. removing spaces and periods is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from Martin's comment you could replace the periods and convert if your data consistently looks like that.

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0), REPLACE('11:00:00 p.m.', '.', ''))
```

OR if you time has a period in it.

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0), REPLACE('11:00:00.123 p.m.','.m.', 'm'))
```

Comment: `REPLACE(str,'.m.', 'm')` might be a bit safer - e.g. if passed a time value like `07:00:00.123 p.m.`

Comment: There is no miliseconds so this was my final solution: TRY_CONVERT(TIME(0), REPLACE(REPLACE( SUBSTRING(@HourInString, CHARINDEX(':', @HourInString)-2,20) , '.', ''), ' ', ''), 108) .